# Какова ценность мата в русском языке?

Tags: этикет, обсценная-лексика

В сети мне попался опрос на  тему "нужен ли мат в русском языке". И, признаться, меня удивило, что большинство участвующих (а опрос проводился в одном сообществе, посвященном русскому языку) проголосовало за то, что мат - это богатство русского языка, которое нужно сохранять.

А что скажут специалисты? Может, я отстал из жизни, и мат - это действительно не неприличная брань, а богатство (не будем касаться его ритуального происхождения - речь о сегодняшнем дне)? Но, что касается меня, то у меня не поворачивается язык произносить такие слова и делается очень неприятно, когда я их слышу от других, особенно, от девушек.

Comment: Я - русский. Поэтому я не употребляю вышеупомянутое "богатство русского языка, которое нужно сохранять".

Вместе с тем, я не возражаю, чтобы завсегдатаи этого форума повульвели (= поболтали) о "русском мате".

Comment: Галактион! А как Вы докажете, что Вы - русский? Вы так часто хотите убедить нас в этом, что поневоле возникают сомнения в правдивости Вашего утверждения. В вопросе "Как пить дать" представлена фотография пьющего Кота. Так вот! Когда Вам ещё раз захочется написать фразу "Я - русский", предъявите, пожалуйста, ксерокопию соответствующей странички паспорта. И без грубостей!

Comment: Я - русский. Поэтому я не планирую предъявлять "ксерокопию соответствующей странички паспорта" ни "русакам", ни "белякам", ни их аналогам.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Столько уже всего сказано-пересказано...
Не хочу повторять, интернет в помощь.
Вы только учтите, что мат - это понятие из области морали.
Устанавливать законодательно моральные нормы - это отдает чем-то не самым свежим.
То ли исламским фундаментализмом, то ли кодексом строителя коммунизма.
Лучше это делать в головах, а не в законах.

Answer (score 6):

Знаете, дело не в том, приличная или неприличная. Никто не утверждает, что мат - это приличная лексика. Дело в том, что мат представляет собой экспрессивную лексику. Он выражает то, что не выразишь ,например, другими словами. Другое дело, надо знать, где его употреблять. Никто не предлагает в обществе вам ругаться матом. Но искоренить и заменить мат - не реально. Статья о мате здесь: [Новая Газета](http://www.novayagazeta.ru/arts/64398.html)

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните примерами Ваше мнение о том, что мат  "выражает то, что не выразишь, например, другими словами."

Comment: Мне как-то до сих пор удавалось выразить приличными словами все свои эмоции

Comment: А если кирпич на ногу?

Answer (score 3):

Из воспоминаний К. С. Станиславского о посещении артистами МХТ Хитровского рынка, места где в начале века селились в Москве все отбросы общества. Для посещения выбрали дом переписчиков.

> Все эти милые ночлежники приняли нас, как старых друзей, так как хорошо знали нас по театру и ролям, которые переписывали для нас. Мы выставили на стол закуску, то есть водку с колбасой, и начался пир. Когда мы объяснили им цель нашего прихода, заключающуюся в изучении жизни бывших людей для пьесы Горького, босяки растрогались до слез…
> Особенно один из ночлежников вспоминал былое. От прежней жизни или в память о ней у него сохранился плохонький рисунок, вырезанный из какого-то иллюстрированного журнала: на нем был нарисован старик отец, в театральной позе, показывающий сыну вексель. Рядом стоит и плачет мать, а сконфуженный сын, прекрасный молодой человек, замер в неподвижной позе, опустив глаза от стыда и горя. По-видимому, трагедия заключалась в подделке векселя. Художник Симов не одобрил рисунка. Боже! Что тогда поднялось! Словно взболтнули эти живые сосуды, переполненные алкоголем, и он бросился им в голову… Они побагровели, перестали владеть собой и озверели. Посыпались ругательства, схватили — кто бутылку, кто табурет, замахнулись, ринулись на Симова… Одна секунда и он не уцелел бы.  Но   тут   бывший   с   нами   Гиляровский   крикнул   громоподобным   голосом   пятиэтажную   ругань , ошеломив сложностью ее конструкции не только  нас , но и самих ночлежников. Они остолбенели от неожиданности, восторга и эстетического удовлетворения. Настроение сразу изменилось. Начался бешеный смех, аплодисменты, овации, поздравления и благодарности за гениальное ругательство, которое спасло нас от смерти или увечья».

Сейчас мы наблюдаем детабуирование мата, когда матерная лексика перестаёт восприниматься как непременное табу. Мат употребляют во всех слоях общества. В искусстве сочиняются довольно хорошие матерные стихи (одна из матерных поэм приписывается и Пушкину), а в современной прозе мат зачастую позволяет лучше выделить персонажа.

Мат не нужно защищать, но и уничтожать его бессмысленно. Если слова появляются, значит это кому-нибудь нужно.

P.S. Сам я мат употребляю только в сугубо мужской компании, если требуется общаться так, чтобы тебя поняли. Я могу выразить любую мысль не прибегая к помощи пониженной лексики, но не всегда слушатель эту мысль без мата поймёт.

Answer (score 1):

Мат как составляющую русской речи не следует стараться уничтожить, так как  необходимость в таких выражениях есть. В то же время в обществе должна быть культура употребления подобных слов, несущих особый энергетический запас и особую информационную ёмкость. Можно обозначить следующие правила:

1) Матом надо уметь пользоваться, применяя его в особенных ситуациях. Превращение мата в междометия говорит об очень низкой культуре человека.

2) Общество должно строго ограничить сферу употребления мата, запретить его употребление в общественных местах, особенно в детской и юношеской среде.

Интересно, что в популярной сейчас книге П. Друкерман "Французские родители не сдаются" есть глава "Позвольте ребенку иметь свое крепкое словцо". Речь идет, конечно, не о мате (в качестве примера приводится многозначное "кака будэн"- какая разница, оставьте меня в  покое, не ваше дело). При этом область применения подобных слов  строго определена: не при учителях, не за столом, только со своими сверстниками. Имеется в виду, что у детей очень много правил и ограничений, им необходимо как-то выпустить пар.

Answer (score 1):

Мат *неприличен*. Этим прилагательным обозначается то, что не должно происходить *при ликах* (святых). Мат *безобразен*: должен звучать *без образов* (святых). Иными словами, мат - явление антикультурное.

Но есть сферы жизни, на которые культура не может и не должна распространять своё влияние. Это деторождение, война и выполнение тяжёлой работы. Там мат незаменим. Он помогает, так сказать, спуститься с небес на грешную землю, способствует МАТериализации процессов. Например, на поле БРАНИ матерная БРАНЬ снимает психологический запрет не убийство (а заодно и на секс, почему во время войны наряду с массовыми убийствами  происходят массовые изнасилования).

Чтобы полностью искоренить мат, необходимо отказаться не только от войн, но и от тяжёлой физической работы и рождения детей. Проблема в том, что многочисленные эфирные чайлд-фри создания не слишком похожи на людей...

..........................................

**Дополнение.**

Для развития и сохранения культуры необходим определённый достаток и чувство защищённости. А вот когда возникает ситуация "не до жиру, быть бы живу", вот тогда и...
Мат - это всегда о выживании рода.

Непрерывно матерящегося в мирное время человека можно сравнить с плачущим младенцем: и тот, и другой кричат о каких-то своих нехватках. И тот, и другой не воспитан (не накормлен).

Comment: А  деторождение  каким  боком  вне  культуры  оказалось ?

Comment: Всеми боками.)))0
Воспитание ребёнка происходит в лоне культуры, а зачатие и рождение - нет.

Comment: В  мире  животных.  Хотя  и  человек  -  скотина.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос некорректен. Что значит "нужен — не нужен"? Он просто есть, и изгнать нельзя, невозможно.
А бабочка-крапивница в природе нужна или нет? Вопрос такого же сорта.

Answer (score 0):

Мат  -  это  отображение  окружающей  действительности  сквозь  призму  полового  акта. Что  на  сегодняшний  день,  само  по  себе - извращение.  В  результате  табуирования  этой  сферы  в  речевой  практике  мат  стал  ещё  и  сквернословием  и  ругательством.  Приобрёл  статус  запретного  плода.        Вопрос - когда ?  И  в  каких  слоях  населения ?   Иногда  создается  впечатление,  что  была  лишь  попытка  табуирования,  но  попытка  безуспешная.   Что,  впрочем,  легко  объясняется  всем  ходом  нашей  истории.
      Кроме   всего  этого   матерная  лексика  отлично  прижилась  в  речи  в  качестве  плеоназмов  (  слов - заместителей).    Но  плеоназмов   много  и  других,  и  не  имеющих  отношения  к  сквернословию.  Изврат  в  данном  случае  -  выбор  слова.  Тоже  самое  относится  и  матерным  фразеологизмам.  Думаю,  что  психиатрия  уже  высказалась  по  этому  вопросу.
    Интересно,  что  восприятие  и  отображение  одних  явлений  через  призму  других - есть  восприятие  и  отображение  художественное. Следовательно  мат - это первобытный  художественный  изврат. 
Но,  в  принципе,  это  обыкновенное  свернословие.  И  надо  очень  постараться,  чтобы  увидеть  в  этом    особое  богатство  русского  языка  ( и  вообще  языка ).

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению, мат - совершенно нормальное явление языка. Кстати, почему Вы говорите о необходимости мата именно в русском языке? Мат существует в каждом языке, как и в русском. Если же вопрос заключается в том, стоит ли употреблять его, то тут нужно говорить о стиле речи, о ситуации и т.д. Без мата язык не может себя полностью реализовать в быту. Матерные слова обладают эксперссивными оттенками, поэтому мы имеем необходимость в некоторых случаях использовать сеи слова. 
Постскриптум: мое мнение субъективно.

Comment: Необходимость  брани ( а  мат - это  брань ) это  не  просто  нормальное  явление  языка,  это,  как  сказал  бы  Остап  Бендер,  медицинский  факт. И  брань  действительно   интернациональна.  И  всюду  она - брань.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, это явление есть и будет. Но это не значит, что надо как можно громче и чаще показывать, что ты знаешь и умело используешь это "богатство". Особенно в общественных местах.

Answer (score 0):

Без мата, думаю, русский язык не будет таким колоритным...

Comment: Да,  для  тех,  кто  любит  сквернословие.

Comment: да люблю ,но редко и в меру...обожаю Фаину Георгиевну ,например, и её высказывания ...